# How to write Python Shell to an output text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to write my Python shell to an output text file. I have some of it written into an output text file but all I need is to now add the number of lines and numbers in each line to my output text file.

I have tried to add another for loop outside the for loop. I've tried putting it inside the for loop and it was just complicated.

Text file list of numbers:

```
1.0,    1.12, 1.123
1.0,1.12,1.123
1
```

Code:

```py
import re
index = 0
comma_string = ', '
outfile = "output2.txt"
wp_string = " White Space Detected"
tab_string = " tab detected"
mc_string = " Missing carriage return"
ne_string = " No Error"
baconFile = open(outfile,"wt")
with open("Version2_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        flag = 0
        carrera = ""
        index = index +1
        print("Line {}: ".format(index))
        baconFile.write("Line {}:  ".format(index))
        if " " in line:                         #checking for whitespace
            carrera = carrera + wp_string + comma_string + carrera
            flag = 1
            a = 1
        if "\t" in line:                        #checking for tabs return
            carrera = carrera + tab_string + comma_string + carrera
            flag = 1
        if '\n' not in line:
            carrera = carrera + mc_string + ne_string + carrera
            flag = 1
        if flag == 0:                           #checking if no error is true by setting flag equal to zero
            carrera = ne_string
        print('\t'.join(str(len(g)) for g in re.findall(r'\d+\.?(\d+)?', line )))
        print (carrera)
        baconFile.write('\t'.join(str(len(g)) for g in re.findall(r'\d+\.?(\d+)?', line ) ))
        baconFile.write(carrera + "\n")

with open("Version2_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    print('Number of Lines: {}'.format(len(content)))
    for i in range(len(content)):
            print('Numbers in Line {}: {}'.format(i+1, len(content[i].split(','))))
            baconFile.write('Number of lines: {}'.format(len(content)))
            baconFile.write('Numbers in Line {}: {}'.format(i+1, len(content[i].split(','))))  
baconFile.close()
```

Expected to write in output file:

```
Line 1: 1    2    3 Tab detected, whitespace detected
Line 2: 1    2    3 No error
Line 3: 1 Missing carriage return No error
Number of Lines: 3
Numbers in Line 1: 3
Numbers in Line 2: 3
Numbers in Line 3: 1
```

Actual from output file:

```
Line 1:  1  3   2White Space Detected, tab detected, White Space Detected, 
Line 2:  1  3   2No Error
Line 3:  0Missing carriage returnNo Error
Number of lines: 3Numbers in Line 1: 3Number of lines: 3Numbers in Line 2: 3Numb
```

Comment: the python shell prints out what is expected but it does not write it all to anoutput file

Comment: If you want to save the output produced by the second loop, you need to `open()` the output file in `"w"` mode, and call `file.write()` instead of calling `print()`.

Comment: I got it, thanks! Do I need to add a + "\n" inside my baconFile.write so it can separate the Numbers in line as  a carriage return

Comment: Yeah, that's one of several differences between `print()` and `write()` (the former adds a newline at the end automatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have closed `baconFile` in the first `open` block, but do not open it again in the second `open` block. Additionally, you never write to `baconFile` in the second `open` block, which makes sense considering you've not opened it there, but then you can't expect to have written to it. It seems you simply forgot to add some `write` statements. Perhaps you confused `write` with `print`. Add those `write` statements in and you should be golden.

```py
baconFile = open(outfile,"wt")
with open("Version2_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:                       
        # ... line processing ...
        baconFile.write(...)  # line format info here
    # baconFile.close()  ## <-- move this
with open("Version2_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    baconFile.write(...)  # number of lines info here
    for i in range(len(content)):
        baconFile.write(...)  # numbers in each line info here
baconFile.close()  # <-- over here
```

Comment: I got it, thanks! If I add a + "\n" inside my baconFile.write will it separate the Numbers in line to a new line?

Comment: Yep. print adds a newline character to the end of the output unless otherwise specified:
`print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`.
In contrast, `write` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a useful trick you can use to make `print` statements send their output to a specified file instead of the screen (i.e. `stdout`):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os
import sys


@contextmanager
def redirect_stdout(target_file):
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = target_file
    yield
    sys.stdout = save_stdout

# Sample usage
with open('output2.txt', 'wt') as target_file:
    with redirect_stdout(target_file):
        print 'hello world'
        print 'testing', (1, 2, 3)

print 'done'  # Won't be redirected.
```

Contents of `output2.txt` file after running the above:

```
hello world
testing (1, 2, 3)
```