# How to Print To Text File?

Tags: python, io-redirection

I want print my output to text file. Jow can I fix my code?

```py
for h3 in parse.find_all('h3', {'class': "_1hETr2dodrTLejwpCPNjNp"}):
     account = '{}:{}:{}'.format(ab_form, ft_form, h3.get_text())
     print(account)
     output = open("./output.txt", "r")
     output.write(account)
```

Comment: To begin with, you should open the file only once, and in write mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875363/355230) to a similar question. In Python 3.4+ you can use the built-in [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) context manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for h3 in parse.find_all('h3', {'class': "_1hETr2dodrTLejwpCPNjNp"}):
        account = '{}:{}:{}\n'.format(ab_form, ft_form, h3.get_text())
        with open("./output.txt", "a") as fd:
            fd.write(account)
```

note \n newline separator and 'a' append mode as you are doing multiple writes

Comment: File "rr.py", line 30
    with open("./output.txt", "w") as 
                                     ^

Comment: with open("./output.txt", "a") as fd:

Comment: File "rr.py", line 27
    for h3 in parse.find_all('h3', {'class': "_1hETr2dodrTLejwpCPNjNp"}):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Please post ALL you and output.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `+` in your file open to create the file if it does not exist.

Also, there is little value opening the file each time through the loop.

```py
with open("./output.txt", "a+") as fd:
  for h3 in parse.find_all('h3', {'class': "_1hETr2dodrTLejwpCPNjNp"}):
    account = '{}:{}:{}\n'.format(ab_form, ft_form, h3.get_text())
    fd.write(account)
```

I will assume that the rest of the script does what you need it to do.